# How to select from a selection box with a variable in the name?

Tags: html, ruby, capybara

I am having trouble using selecting from this select element.

```
<select name="vehicle_attrs[position_count]" class="mb1"><option>Position / Quantity</option><option>Front</option><option>Rear</option></select>
```

I have tried

```
select('Front', :from=>'mb1')
select('Front', :from=>'vehicle_attrs[position_count]')
select('Front', :from=>'vehicle_attrs[1]')
```

All of them result in a can not find selection box error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never liked how restrictive Capybara's concept of a 'locator' is (i.e. must have a name/id/label), but if you dig into the source code, those helpful methods like `select`, `click_on`, and `fill_in` are just wrappers for `find` and some native method of [Element](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element), which takes arbitrary CSS, and works in almost all situations.  In this case, you could use:

```
find('[name="vehicle_attrs[position_count]"]').find('option', text: 'Front').select_option
```

Since dropdowns often have multiple similar options, where one is a substring of the other, you might consider using an exact string match, like

```
find('[name="vehicle_attrs[position_count]"]').find('option', text: /\AFront\z/).select_option
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `select` - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method - we can see that the `from` option takes "The id, Capybara.test_id atrtribute, name or label of the select box".

Neither 'mb1' or 'vehicle_attrs[1]' are any of those so they would be expected to fail.

'vehicle_attrs[position_count]' is the name so assuming the box is actually visible on the page (not replaced with a JS driven select widget, etc), that should work.  If it doesn't, then edit your question and add the full exact error message you get when trying to use it. Of course if there is only one select box on the page with an option of 'Front' then you don't need to specify the `from` option at all and can just do

```
select 'Front'
```